# How to programmatically change language?

Tags: android, localization

I want to programmatically change the language.

So I have built two xml files.

```
values-it
-->string.xml

values-en
-->string.xml
```

This is the code in MainActivity to change the language of the whole application:

//ITALIAN

```
Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("it");
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

//ENGLISH

```
Resources res2 = getApplicationContext().getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm2 = res2.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf2 = res2.getConfiguration();
conf2.locale = new Locale("en");
res2.updateConfiguration(conf2, dm2);
```

Now if I set the English language (for example) the code is executed with no error, but the label doesn't not change its text.
If I change the orientation of my device, the label changes its text correctly.

Now how can I modify my code to automatically refresh the label?

Comment: try to call your code in onResume().

Comment: Hi, here you are a link telling you how to reload changes without closing the activity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644377/changing-locale-force-activity-to-reload-resources

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh activity after changing language (Locale) inside application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049207/how-to-refresh-activity-after-changing-language-locale-inside-application)

Comment: conf2.locale and res2.updateConfiguration() are deprecated. :S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DashboardActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.languages);
            // Add the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.english, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String languageToLoad = "en"; // your language
                    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    rEditor.putString("language", languageToLoad);
                    rEditor.commit();



                    Intent refresh = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(refresh);
                    finish();

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.gujarati, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog

                    String languageToLoad = "gu"; // your language
                    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    rEditor.putString("language", languageToLoad);
                    rEditor.commit();


                    Intent refresh = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(refresh);
                    finish();

                }
            });

            builder.create().show();
```

you have to reload activity to show new language text means restart.

Comment: what is `rEditor` ?

Comment: sharedPreference Editor for saving data.https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: resource.updateConfiguration is deprecated. Now what is alternative?

Comment: check this link... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated/40291570

Comment: How to check language from SharedPreferences and change language on app start up for not restarting app on start up? At what place it should be done?

Answer (score 5):

you need to refresh your activity to load resources which it does incase of changing the orientation. try this

```
private void restartActivity() { 
 Intent intent = getIntent(); 
 finish(); 
 startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a call to recreate() be simpler than writing a custom method?

Answer (score 3):

If you have not solved with your problem yet, you can try this. It works for me, hope so it will help you. You can refer it in future

```
mSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.language_switch);

    mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    mSwitch.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    String languageToLoad = "es";
                    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.setLocale(locale);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "spanish is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                } else {
                    String languageToLoad = "en";
                    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.setLocale(locale);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "english is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to put all `TextView.setText()` in a method. Call that method in your `onResume();` to set it the first time. Then recall that method when you have reset the language. (the Activity goes trough the `onStart()` `onResume()` etc when you change orientation)

Comment: it's not just about the strings ... sometimes directions are important too, RTL or LTR

Comment: Good call, this seems a good way to deal with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964488/how-to-make-the-text-direction-from-right-to-left

Comment: actually dug around a bit more and found the correct solution, and put it in a gist: https://gist.github.com/muhammad-naderi/0ff264e6cc07df904bc88a9f7efbe57d

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do:

`com.android.internal.app.LocalePicker.updateLocales(LocaleList locales)`