# Android: Change Languages (string.xml) programmatically

Tags: android, localization

In our Android app, we have an option for the user to change the language, which means he can select whether he want to use English or Sinhala. The default is always in English. We have one string.xml for English and another for Sinhala.

I was referring Android documents about "localization" but that is not exactly what I am looking for, I can't ask the user to change his phone settings. I also noticed programmatic localization which is discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244889/load-language-specific-string-from-resource) but most users do not recommend it due to loads of errors (anyway these posts are pretty old)

So, what's the best way of changing the String?XML file, with the preferred language of a user? It seems not easy on Android.

Or, is this is simply not a good idea?

Comment: you should read this.... Here we describe how to open this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454353/how-to-programmatically-change-language/37454658#37454658

Comment: That method is subjected to issues, as far as I know