# Get specific string resource translation at application runtime

Tags: android, xml, resources, translation, android-resources

In Xamarin.Android I have String resource translated in German and a default English translation. While the app is running it only obtains strings in German. How do I make it obtain the English translation instead without changing device's locale?

`<string name="exampleResource">Example string</string>`

`<string name="exampleResource">Beispiel string</string>`

I need the second translation shown in Xamarin application at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the culture of you resx object?

```
 AppResources.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-EN");
```

Comment: Following isn't working:

```CultureInfo englishGBCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
                    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = englishGBCulture;
                    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = englishGBCulture;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = englishGBCulture;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = englishGBCulture;```

Comment: sorry I ddn`t read that you are workin in native xamarin. I think that this post can help you for update your resources after culture thread is changed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644377/changing-locale-force-activity-to-reload-resources

Comment: Can't I just specify the culture for the value returned by GetString() instead of changing the language for the whole app, i. e. AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(index, AppResources.Culture)?